# addStream in firefox dont work - webrtc

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I try use webrtc in a app, for realtime comunication, this in chrome work fine but in firefox i get error in function addStream, i am using adapter.js i suppose what it will solved all error of compatibility but the error keep.

```
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);

pc.onicecandidate = function (evt) { 
  // my code here
}

pc.onnegotiationneeded = function (evt) { 
  // my code here
}

if(isChromium) {
  object_user.pc.onaddstream = function (evt) {

  };
} else { 
  object_user.pc.ontrack = function (evt) {

  };
}


if(isChromium) {
  object_user.pc.addStream(window.localstream); // <- get error in firefox
}else{
  object_user.pc.addTrack(window.localstream);
}
```

I try to change addStream by addTrack of firefox but I get "Not enough arguments to RTCPeerConnection.addTrack."

Comment: what exactly is window.localstream at the time you're trying to add it?
You can still use addStream in Firefox despite the deprecation warning.

Comment: Please include error messages!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for addTrack requires 2 argumuments, track and stream, which is probably why you get an error.

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> rtpSender = RTCPeerConnection.addTrack(track, stream...);
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *track*
>
> A MediaStreamTrack object representing the media track to add to the
>   peer connection.
>
> *stream...*
>
> One or more MediaStream objects in which the specified track are to be
>   contained.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addTrack